# Unable to get text in firefox browser but working in IE

Tags: selenium

I need to get the text from text Area, I fetching the text using .getText(), it is working in IE but not in Firefox.

Coudld anyone please help me?

I need to do cross browser test execution. Most of the test are failing bcoz of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use JQuery and then use `$('#id_of_textarea').val();`

Comment: Thank you very much for your rapid response.
I am using selenium webdriver using xpath, css, name etc. I am locating the elements, but I dont know how to use jquery. Can you pls tell me how to do this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with selenium however does it work if you use the native JS function innerHTML? Like so: `var text = document.getElementById('id_of_textarea').innerHTML;`

Comment: Yes I tried using javascript but it is fetching 'null'.
The text is there in the field but in HTML tag it is not displaying.

Comment: Atleast if the text is displayed in any of the attributes we can easily fetch the value but here the suitiation is little different.

Comment: Probably your textarea has something like `display:none`?  Please copy the code of the tag (and it's insides).

Comment: the tag is like below in firefox 
<textarea style="width: 500px;" rows="5" cols="1" class="" id="QAQIDescription"></textarea>

In IE 
<textarea class="" id="QAQIDescription" style="width: 500px;" rows="5" cols="1">
Text - Beginning the Immediate operational period.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox & Chrome, `textarea` content can be access with

```
.getAttribute("value")
```

But I don't know what's happen on IE with this solution.

Hope that helps.